# USB CDC with ARM keil

Tags: serial-port, usb, lpc

I want to USB CDC as part off my project what is simplest way to do that ?

i tried some project in keil arm but the speed is to low and there is so many problem with that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better to use a red codes project in LPCXpresso V 5.2 . its free and safe . 
you can find it [here](http://www.lpcware.com/lpcxpresso) !